# Conditional Probability with uncertainty

Tags: probability

My friend and I have been debating over this for hours and seem to not get to a conclusion nor wrap our heads around. Anyone has an indication for what we need to look in literature to get a proper explanation?

> You have two cups and are 80% sure that the marble is under one of
> them. 40% that it is under the left and 40% that it is under the right
> cup. You take a look under the left cup and find out that the marble
> is not there (condition). What is then the conditional probability
> then that the marble is under the right cup?

We've defined the events as follows:

- $A$: marble is under the left cup on the first look $\longrightarrow \mathbb P(A)=40\%$
- $B$: marble is under the right cup on the second look

And came to the conclusion:

- $\mathbb P(B|\neg A)$: marble is under the right cup if it was not left on the first look: $80\%$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is only one marble, $$P(B| \bar A ) = \frac{P(B \cap \bar A)}{P(\bar A)} =\frac 23$$

$P(B\cap \bar A)=40\% $ as this event is equivalent to the marble being in the right cup.

$P(\bar A)= (100-40)\%=60\% $ as this event is equivalent to the marble just not being in the first cup.

Answer (score 1):

Tavish' answer provides a **formal** proof.  The informal approach is:

There are two possibilities:

- The marble is under the first cup
- The marble is not under the first cup **and** the ratio of the probability that the marble is under the 2nd cup vs the probability that the marble is not under the 2nd cup is **40 to 20**.

Once you determine that the first case above is impossible, you are left with the second case.